# Gnome Files (Nautilus) cannot retrieve SMB share list of a server when double-clicking

Tags: gnome, samba, nautilus, smb, file-sharing

I am running Gnome Arch. In Files, Other Locations, Networks, there is `Server`. If I double-click it, Files says "Unable to access location." If I type the server name `smb://server` and then click "Connect" at the bottom of that window, then it shows the share list.

Since the two actions (double-clicking the server icon and typing the server name/clicking connect) are essentially the same thing, I don't understand why the former fails and the latter succeeds. Unless this is a bug, how can I solve the problem?

The `Server` is a Linux PC running Samba to provide SMB shares. I tried the similar thing on KDE Neon (6.0 beta). Dolphin also showed `Server` in its network list, and double-clicking it showed the share list.

[image]